# Referencing objects in mongoose array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose user model which has the following schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Question = require('./questions');
let questionSchema = mongoose.model('Question').schema

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : {
      type: String,
      required: true        
  },
  questions : {
      type: [questionSchema],
     required: false
  }
}, {collection: 'users'});
```

Users can add questions and other users have to answer the questions and so I have a question and answer model with the following schemas.
This is the question schema:

```
let questionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  owner : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  answered : {
    type : Boolean,
    required : true,
  },
  text : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  answers : {
    type : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
  }
});
```

This is the answer schema:

```
let answersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  question : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Question'
  },
  owner : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User'
  },
  text : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  correct : {
    type : Boolean,
    required : true
  }
});
```

My problem is that my question objects which are in the array of the users don't seem to be consistent with the question objects. Here is how I push an answer to the `answers` array in the question objects.

```
    Question.findOne({_id : data._id}, (err, question) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let answer = new Answer({
        question : data._id,
        owner : data.owner,
        text : req.body.answer_text,
        correct : false
    });
    answer.save((err)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        question.answers.push(answer);
        question.save((err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    });
```

By inspection I can see that this successfully adds the answers to the array in the question objects by typing `db.questions.find()` in the mongo shell program. In other words the `answers` array of the questions are populated. However, the `answers` array belonging to the questions in the `User` documents are empty regardless of how many answers are actually there. I was under the impression that since my questions had the same `_id`  value as those in the User's questions array, any changes I made to the questions objects would automatically be reflected by the questions objects in the user array. How do I make the User's questions array update their `answers` field to reflect the changes made to the question objects?

Comment: Nothing in this code modifies the `User` at all. It does not happen "automatically" and you should know that by now since you are demonstrating updating a `question` with an answer. You actually need to similarly push the question  to the user as well of course. Unless you already have them there and are asking why "user" does not appear "updated", in which case there is nothing to update here. It's a "reference" so nothing in the user needs to change,

Comment: @NeilLunn I already have them there but user does not update. I can see that because I have the question objects directly in there (not a reference) and in those question objects the answers arrays are empty. I read in a tutorial that I can use sub documents (as I’m attempting) or references which is what I’m doing with the question and answers.

Comment: Okay. You appear to be doing something really wrong because you you have `question.save()` ( and `Question.find()` even ) which means you registered a model even though you embedded the schema as well. Those are not reading from the `User`. In short either reference everything or embed everything. Mixing leads to misunderstandings like you have here. If you `questions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]` then it's referenced. Depending on how you added items the `_id` values "might" be okay, or you might have messed them up completely.

Comment: your questions should be array of ids like `questions :[{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Questions' }]` and your answers should be `[{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]`

Comment: @Ashish I thought about doing it that way but I need to loop through them and I thought it would be inefficient to look up the object from each id in a loop. For example I would need to look up the object from the id just to check the correct field and then look up the next object from the next id to check it’s correct field and so on. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: yes it can be done easily and probably the best approach or you don't need to put the array of questions in users and answers in questions, only put the user_id in questions and questions_id in answers